# React Native: onContentSizeChange event on TextInput element does not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a problem with TextInput event 'onContentSizeChange' on Android device. 
Actually it is not been fired when I type message until the end of line and text goes to the next line the height of TextInput is not updated.

example:

```
return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        multiline={Boolean(true)}
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({text})
        }}
        onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height})
        }}
        style={[ additionalStyles, {height: this.state.height}, {fontSize: config.defaultFontSize} ]}
        value={this.state.text}
        underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
      />
    )
```

Does anybody know why it may happens?

P.S. Helped using onChange instead of onContentSizeChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [React Native issue #11692](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11692). This looks like it will be fixed in an upcoming release. It's not clear, and it was only fixed a couple of weeks ago but maybe it will be in 0.46.

Comment: Helped using onChange instead of onContentSizeChange, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try onContentSizeChange

```
onContentSizeChange={e=>{
                    let inputH = Math.max(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height, 35)
                    if(inputH>120) inputH =100
                    setIputHeight(inputH)
                }}
```

Answer (score 0):

onContentSizeChange does not return the size of the content, but on the container. It's still not fixed, which is also documented in an [issue on the official react-native github repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29702)